# Event hub & Azure Data Explorer not ingesting all messages

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

For the last 12 hours, I am noticing `Outgoing Messages` in the Event hub are too few than incoming messages. & more worrying thing is that event hub `Outgoing Messages` frequency is the same (Like service is intentionally doing it). You can see in the below images that after 12 PM `Outgoing Messages` are 100 per half hour. But there are more messages available.

[image]

### Only Outgoing messages with Zoom

[image]

### What I am doing

We are pushing application logs to Event Hub & Developer can watch these logs in ADX cluster.

### Event hub configuration

- **Zone Redundancy**: Enabled
- **Pricing tier**: Standard
- **Throughput Unit**: 1 Unit
- **Auto-inflate throughput**: Disabled

### ADX configuration

- **Engine type**: V3
- **Compute specifications**: Standard_D11_v2
- **Instance count**: 2

### Event hub Ingestion metrics in ADX

[image]

### About batching

After some googling, I found about batching. I thought may be resources are misconfigured but this is not the case

#### DB batch policy

```sql
.show database altslogsdb policy ingestionbatching
```

##### Output

```json
"PolicyName": IngestionBatchingPolicy,
"EntityName": [altslogsdb],
"Policy": null,
"ChildEntities": [
  "alts_logs_table"
],
"EntityType": Database,
```

#### Table batch policy

```sql
.show table alts_logs_table policy ingestionbatching
```

##### Output

```json
"PolicyName": IngestionBatchingPolicy,
"EntityName": [altslogsdb].[alts_logs_table],
"Policy": null,
"ChildEntities": ,
"EntityType": Table,
```

## May be issue got resolved automatically

After more than 24 hours, it may be got automatically resolved. I also created a support ticket. I don't know it got resolved automatically or Microsoft resolved it. Waiting for a mail from a support person.

[image]

As you can see, 3 spikes at last, I think that event hub was dropping messages because no messages are available in ADX & issue is there in that period also.

### Update

Created ticket for Microsoft. Event hub and Azure data explorer teams are looking into it. The ticket is open for the last 2 months.

Comment: Did you check ADX if there is anything in the logs? E.g. the insights blade?

Comment: @AlexAIT I checked logs & there is no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple checks that you should do:

1. As Alex said above, take a look at the "insights" blade to see if there are ingestion failures on Azure Data Explorer side.
2. You can check the EventHub ingestion metrics in your Azure Data Explorer cluster metrics: [image]
3. Check to see if there are errors on the EventHub such as throtteling

If you can't find the information there, please open a support ticket.

Comment: Hi @Avnera, I checked logs & metrics, but there is nothing in logs, and a metrics graph is added in question. Thanks.

Comment: Since you opened a support ticket, can you share its number?